# jquery tabs not firing after content loaded via ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-tabs

I have an index page, in wich  I have jquery.js and jquery.tabs.js included.
this page load content via ajax into a . The content is a set of tabs, their contents and at the bottom of the loaded content I have a call to tabs().
in FF it only works when I load content after refreshing the index page, and if I hit the link to reload the content, it stops working. in IE it's not working at all.

These are my tabs:

```
<ul id="horz-tabs">
 <li><a href="#tab1">tab1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#tab2">tab2</a></li>
 <li><a href="#tab3">tab3</a></li>
</ul>
```

then I have the containers following, and at the very end of the page loaded via ajax I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
 $('#horz-tabs a').tabs(); 
//--></script>
```

My ajax function loads the page properly. I am wondering how I can fix this issue. Thanks for any help or advice.

The ajax loading function is as follow

```
<script>

    function async(target, href) {          
    var loading = '<div class="loading">Loading</div>';  
      jQuery.ajax({
        url: href,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $(target).prepend(loading);
        },
        error: function() {
            $(target).html("<span class='error'>Failed</span>");
        },

        success: function(results) {
            $(target).html(results);
        }
    })
}

</script
```

Comment: Maybe try `$(function(){ $('#horz-tabs a').tabs(); });` to make sure the document is ready.

Comment: what do you mean by `this page load content via ajax into a`

Comment: can you share the ajax loading code also

Comment: @NathanBouscal I tried that with no result

Comment: @ArunPJohny sorry, via ajax into a <div>.

Comment: @user1709251 and how do you call this function.?

Comment: @DipeshParmar $("body").on("click", ".ajax", function (event) { ...., So all the links with class ajax call this function. the function ajax function seems fine to me, it's the tabs. I wonder if I should call them when ajax success

Comment: is the html `<ul id="horz-tabs">
 <li><a href="#tab1">tab1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#tab2">tab2</a></li>
 <li><a href="#tab3">tab3</a></li>
</ul>` loaded via ajax

Comment: @ArunPJohny yes it is loaded via ajax, along with the call to tabs()

Answer (score 0):

Look like you are loading the tab html via ajax, that could be the problem since when your script is running the dom for the tab elements may not be existing.

So you need to have a success callback to the async load method and add execute `$('#horz-tabs a').tabs();` in the load success callback.

```
function async(target, href) {
    var loading = '<div class="loading">Loading</div>';
    return jQuery.ajax({
        url : href,
        beforeSend : function() {
            $(target).prepend(loading);
        },
        error : function() {
            $(target).html("<span class='error'>Failed</span>");
        },

        success : function(results) {
            $(target).html(results);
        }
    });
}
```

Then

```
async('some-div', 'tab-url').done(function(){
    $('#horz-tabs a').tabs(); 
})
```

Comment: it weird, it only works once. when I refresh the whole page (index) and load content by clicking an ajax link it works, it I click that same link again, it does not.